# Flutter - Text overflow in Row when another widget in the same Row is flexible

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to implement a `Row` having two `Text` widgets and a middle line like this:

[image]

The following code is my current implementation.

```dart
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Text(
      'Text',
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
        height: 1,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.black
        )
      ),
    ),
    Text(
      'Right Text'
    )
  ]
)
```

The problem of this code is that the left text overflows if it is long like this:

[image]

The expected output is:

[image]

Wrapping the first `Text` widget with a `Flexible` can solve the overflow issue, but the output is not the same as the expected output because of the `Expanded` widget that fills the space between two `Text` widgets with a line.

[image]

How can I achieve this? Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Any solution for this?